# Are OpenSSL generated pem keys compatible with Erlang Crypto

Tags: openssl, cryptography, erlang, ecdsa

I have generated a private key using OpenSSL:

```
ARWIN-TIO:/tmp$ openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out key.pem
ARWIN-TIO:/tmp$ cat key.pem
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIINcLTcsL/VhTBEsp1gRgHtO9lLzypm7oYjwViz3bWZCoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAE8kuZsfDhQdkkYjVRla3ShxAlsbLwOt8jUsKyebB7GGWxnBiDqRoB
bSxkkd+APIM/4+lYwIDAx5+EmIIuUIRdcA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And I'm struggling to use it in Erlang's Crypto module:

```
ARWIN-TIO:/tmp$ erl
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.3.5.6] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

Eshell V10.3.5.6  (abort with ^G)
1> Message = <<"Hello">>.
<<"Hello">>
2> PrivateKey = base64:decode("MHcCAQEEIINcLTcsL/VhTBEsp1gRgHtO9lLzypm7oYjwViz3bWZCoAoGCCqGSM49AwEHoUQDQgAE8kuZsfDhQdkkYjVRla3ShxAlsbLwOt8jUsKyebB7GGWxnBiDqRoBbSxkkd+APIM/4+lYwIDAx5+EmIIuUIRdcA==").
<<48,119,2,1,1,4,32,131,92,45,55,44,47,245,97,76,17,44,
  167,88,17,128,123,78,246,82,243,202,153,...>>
3> Signature = crypto:sign(ecdsa, sha256, Message, [PrivateKey, prime256v1]).
** exception error: badkey
     in function  crypto:sign/5
        called as crypto:sign(ecdsa,sha256,<<"Hello">>,
                              [<<48,119,2,1,1,4,32,131,92,45,55,44,47,245,97,76,17,44,
                                 167,88,17,128,123,78,...>>,
                               prime256v1],
                              [])
```

When I generate the keys using Erlang's Crypto module, it works:

```
ARWIN-TIO:/tmp$ erl
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.3.5.6] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

Eshell V10.3.5.6  (abort with ^G)
1> Message = <<"Hello">>.
<<"Hello">>
2> {PublicKey, PrivateKey} = crypto:generate_key(ecdh, crypto:ec_curve(prime256v1)).
{<<4,149,38,43,104,132,214,232,147,174,88,185,96,250,185,
   181,170,8,231,61,255,134,143,255,4,136,249,9,...>>,
 <<130,195,50,229,108,51,72,27,219,145,250,244,116,3,52,
   234,13,60,148,175,112,192,140,110,232,46,116,...>>}
3> Signature = crypto:sign(ecdsa, sha256, Message, [PrivateKey, prime256v1]).
<<48,70,2,33,0,252,243,117,254,110,176,232,185,121,156,93,
  105,74,115,115,247,83,82,17,32,167,254,223,74,...>>
```

I noticed that the Erlang private keys are way shorter than the OpenSSL one:

```
4> base64:encode(PrivateKey).
<<"gsMy5WwzSBvbkfr0dAM06g08lK9wwIxu6C50rwKaBvw=">>
```

Which is way shorter than the one generated with "openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out key.pem"

Why are the OpenSSL keys different/not working with Erlang's Crypto module? How can I make them compatible?

Thanks.

Comment: The issues are explored in depth in this mailing list thread http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2015-February/083574.html as well as in a final summary blog post here: https://zxq9.com/archives/1004 . The incompatibility turns out to be very minor: there is an extra ASN.1 field included in one format that the other rejects (though both *should* accept it according to the standard). You can avoid the whole thing by using DER format, removing the extra field, or converting to DER and back again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking at is a X9.62 encoded private key that got PEM encoded in addition. You've removed the PEM header lines and base 64 decoded, so now you just have the X9.62 encoded private key left.

As you seem to be using OpenSSL, first decode the base64 so you can do:

```sh
openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in private_prime256v1.bin
```

Which will give you:

```
     0:d=0  hl=2 l= 119 cons: SEQUENCE          
     2:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01
     5:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:
        835C2D372C2FF5614C112CA75811807B4EF652F3CA99BBA188F0562CF76D6642
    39:d=1  hl=2 l=  10 cons: cont [ 0 ]        
    41:d=2  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :prime256v1
    51:d=1  hl=2 l=  68 cons: cont [ 1 ]        
    53:d=2  hl=2 l=  66 prim: BIT STRING
```

You haven't clearly shown the full extend of the public / private keys, but it looks like they are just the "flat" representations of the secret S and, for the public key, the uncompressed point W.

So that would be the OCTET STRING in the parsed private key (the final BIT STRING contains the optional public key, the uncompressed point W):

```
835C2D372C2FF5614C112CA75811807B4EF652F3CA99BBA188F0562CF76D6642
```

So this explains the *why*. I don't exactly know how to parse structures like this, but you may not have to. It seems like Erlang already has a function that does this for you called `public_key:pem_decode` which should just take the entire `openssl` generated key. According to [the documentation](https://erlang.org/doc/apps/public_key/using_public_key.html) it should also parse private keys.

As I'm not a Erlang programmer I cannot test this easily, so please let me know.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. I tried what you said:

`1> DecodedPem = lists:nth(1, public_key:pem_decode(<<-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY... omitted>>)).
{'ECPrivateKey',<<48,119,2,1,1,4,32,138,173,152,213,63,43,
                  153,68,224,253,104,124,88,4,114,59,238,
                  49,67,93,...>>,
                not_encrypted}`

And I am now trying to figure out how to use this with `public_key:sign(Msg, DigestType, Key)`. I believe that I also have to use `public_key:pem_entry_decode` but still fiddling around.

Answer (score 0):

With Maarten's guidance I managed to figure it out (did not know that my OpenSSL Private Key was "X9.62" encoded; I thought it was only in base64). It turns out that you need to use the `public_key` module instead of the `crypto` module.

Here is an example of how to use OpenSSL keys w/ Erlang.

Generate a private key:

```
ARWIN-TIO:/tmp$ openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out private_key.pem
ARWIN-TIO:/tmp$ cat private_key.pem
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIGpSqNErkMHbjdeBQBI6NdlK8QgFluCJvGhkt3g5n5zboAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAE43/FB66JPZ2JCbL+e7b4TVpDJAOeeaHmy7NPYL1cOVJFRBux91M4
QYBu1s5DigaQdi/Qz7KK/Yr5EMktgulXHA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And a corresponding public key:

```
ARWIN-TIO:/tmp$ openssl ec -in private_key.pem -pubout -out public_key.pub
ARWIN-TIO:/tmp$ cat public_key.pub
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE43/FB66JPZ2JCbL+e7b4TVpDJAOe
eaHmy7NPYL1cOVJFRBux91M4QYBu1s5DigaQdi/Qz7KK/Yr5EMktgulXHA==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Then in Erlang you sign a message like this:

```
(2020-01-02 20:51:56) ARWIN-TIO:/tmp$ erl
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.3.5.6] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

Eshell V10.3.5.6  (abort with ^G)
1> Message = <<"My Secret Message">>,
1> 
1> PrivatePem = lists:nth(1, public_key:pem_decode(<<"-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
1> MHcCAQEEIGpSqNErkMHbjdeBQBI6NdlK8QgFluCJvGhkt3g5n5zboAoGCCqGSM49
1> AwEHoUQDQgAE43/FB66JPZ2JCbL+e7b4TVpDJAOeeaHmy7NPYL1cOVJFRBux91M4
1> QYBu1s5DigaQdi/Qz7KK/Yr5EMktgulXHA==
1> -----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----">>)),
1>
1> PrivateKey = public_key:pem_entry_decode(PrivatePem),
1> Signature = public_key:sign(Message, sha256, PrivateKey).
<<48,68,2,32,64,80,146,169,96,232,174,140,196,59,46,54,
  107,199,145,184,86,181,79,168,165,107,54,157,222,...>>
```

And you can verify it like this:

```
2> PublicPem = lists:nth(1, public_key:pem_decode(<<"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
2> MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE43/FB66JPZ2JCbL+e7b4TVpDJAOe
2> eaHmy7NPYL1cOVJFRBux91M4QYBu1s5DigaQdi/Qz7KK/Yr5EMktgulXHA==
2> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----">>)),
2> 
2> PublicKey = public_key:pem_entry_decode(PublicPem),
2> VerifyResult = public_key:verify(Message, sha256, Signature, PublicKey),
2> VerifyResult.
true
```